# Python - Cumsum function infinitely looping, repeating over same data even when finished

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a large scale database that contains ~100,000 rows and ~30 columns. I'd like to pull data from two of the columns (name of product & quantity purchased), and implement the cumsum function on the quantity purchased for each unique product. Although I am able to group by product name and generate cumulative values in a third column, the cumsum function does not end where the dataset itself ends. Rather, it resets from the beginning. The practical result of this is that after all the products sold for a day have been accounted for with the cumulative sum function, it will reiterate through the same dataframe, essentially repeating the process 3-5 times until the output (a csv file) is unable to continue due to Excel restrictions on file sizes.

Any input for why this error may be occurring would be greatly appreciated. Below I have pasted an anonymized version of the code I am having troubles with.

```
    `df = pd.read_excel(final_path, usecols=[2, 4])
for rowIndex, row in df.iterrows():  # iterate over rowsdf = df.sort_values(['Name']).reset_index(drop=True)df['TotalQty'] = df.groupby(['Name'])['Qty'].cumsum()
filtered_df = df.sort_values(['Qty'], ascending = False).drop_duplicates(['Name']).sort_index()
filtered_df.to_csv(month + "_" + date + "_" + ".csv", mode='a', header=None)`
```

Thank you in advance for the input! This is my first time posting on Stack Overflow & I greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: Please provide a minimum reproducible example with the expected input and output.

Comment: Pandas has a cumsum function, not sure why you are have a loop there. And the code is very unclear. [mcve]